# Pubnub and arduino with ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, pubnub, firmata

I want to upload my 4 sensor readings on pubnub on a gauge chart. I am using arduino uno and ultra-sonic sensor HC-SR04. I am following this link https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-10-05-streaming-sensor-readings-realtime-gauge-chart/ [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-10-05-streaming-sensor-readings-realtime-gauge-chart/) exactly and have placed my own pub sub keys. Uploaded the firmata sketch on arduino. Run the server side code through command prompt and i get repl initialized and values from A0 pin are being showed on console. next i copy the code of client side on notepad++ and run it in chrome. The gauge chart appears but it's empty, i can't see any reading flickering in it. The console output is shown. I don't know where the problem is. I have also tried de-activating my firewall but no use. For the time being i am just sending A0 pin values, then i would work how to send the distance value, and then multiple gauge charts for multiple distances. Thankyou for any help.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sta8a.png)

Comment: just to clarify, you haven't modified the example code at all except for changing the keys?

Comment: Yes, I havent modified the code except changing for keys.